# How to compile Mesa with debug symbols?

Tags: apt, compiling, gcc, mesa

I want to modify Mesa's source code and build it with debugging symbols enabled. I downloaded and built the sources with these commands:

```
sudo apt build-dep libgl1-mesa-dev
apt source libgl1-mesa-dev
export CFLAGS='-O0 -ggdb3'
export CXXFLAGS='-O0 -ggdb3'
dpkg-buildpackage -rfakeroot -uc -b
sudo dpkg -i *.deb
```

My modifications are now enabled, but there are no debug symbols. According to [Mesa's website](https://www.mesa3d.org/debugging.html), I shold enable debug symbols by setting `-g` flag in Make-config file, but there is no such file.

Assuming it fixes my issue, where do I put the `-g` flag before compiling Mesa?

Comment: Less relevant for development, but useful for debugging, I found it's possible to install [Debug Symbol Packages](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Debug%20Symbol%20Packages) using `apt`, provided you've first enabled the debug symbol repositories. For example: 
`sudo apt install libgl1-mesa-dri-dbgsym`